# How to use inline CSS by th:style using "The ? : operator" in ThymeLeaf

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I am trying to put border color red if a student is fail by using following expression

```
<div class="image_wrap" th:style="${student.studentExamStatus}?border-style: solid;border-color: red;:">
```

but I am getting following exception 
Request processing failed; nested exception is `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${student.studentExamStatus}?border-style: solid;border-color: red;:"`

${student.studentExamStatus} will return either 0 or 1 based student passed exam or not.

Comment: Think you'll need to nest your style statements in single quotes. Otherwise Thymeleaf will try to treat the colon in the style as an operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Andrew said, you need to need to nest your style statements in single quotes. And you must include your expression inside the brackets :

```
<div class="image_wrap" th:style="${student.studentExamStatus ? 'border-style: solid;border-color: red;' : ''}">
```